# How to write python test case for Exception block effectively

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to write test case for exception block for my python code. The test code passes in my local but fails in sonar scan. The sample code is below :

```
def testMethod(var1: List[str]):
    try:
        Some code blocks

        for item in var1:
            some block of codes
    except Exception as e:
        return var1
```

My sample test code is below:

```
class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_testMethod(self):
        from main import testMethod
        testMethod(pd.Dataframe())
        self.assertRaises(AttributeError)
```

Th above test case passes in my machine but fails during Sonar scan. What am I missing??

Comment: try `class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_testMethod(self):
        from main import testMethod
        with self.assertRaises(AttributeError):
            testMethod(pd.DataFrame())`

Comment: Hi @NIKUNJPATEL, thanks for responding, however, the above solution also is not working. No matter what I pass instead of dataframe to fail the case, it giving me error "AssertionError: AttributeError not raised." I even tried by passing a numerical value but no use.

Comment: `class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_testMethod(self):
        from main import testMethod
        with self.assertRaises(AttributeError):
            testMethod(pd.DataFrame(['data1', 'data2']))`.  Where `pd.DataFrame(['data1', 'data2'])` you need to pass your actual data for test.

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL, code wont fail if we use dataframe, I tried by passing integer value but its not working. Infact, code fails in my machine itself with the same error stated in my comment.

Comment: You are handling all types of exceptions using `except Exception` so your code actually does not raise any exception. You should not catch `AttributeError` to let assertion handle it. Consider adding `if isinstance(e, AttributeError): raise e` to your `except` block